# How can I refer to a file as the stream for fgets()?

Tags: c, fgets

fgets() returns a string from a provided stream. One is stdin, which is the user input from the terminal. I know how to do this, but if I am using compiled c code in applications, this is not very useful. It would be more useful if I could get a string from a file. That would be cool. Apparently, there is some way to provide a text file as the stream. Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv){
    char *TextFromFile[16];
    fgets(TextFromFile, 16, /*stream that refers to txt file*/);
    printf("%s\n", TextFromFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose there is a text file in the same directory as the c file. How can I make the printf() function print the contents of the text file?

Comment: Warning: `char* x[16]` is an array of *sixteen character pointers*, not an array of sixteen characters. If this code compiles quietly you need to turn on more warnings because that `fgets` call is invalid.

Comment: [man fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

Comment: Your question states the text file is in the same directory as the C source file. There is in general no way for the running program to know the directory of the C source file from which it was compiled. You will have to make some sort of arrangement to convey this information or to put the text file in a known location. (Keeping it in the same directory as the executable file is a possibility, as that directory can be derived from the `argv[0]` passed to `main`.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["#include" a text file in a C program as a char\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char)

Comment: @NoDataFound How is it even remotely a duplicate?

Comment: Because you say _suppose there is a text file in the same directory as the c file. How can I make the printf function print the contents of the text file?_ You don't ask _how to read the content of any file on the filesystem_ (which is answered by ryyker). And if you want to read the whole file that's another matter involving buffer and reallocation which is answered by this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381080/reading-all-content-from-a-text-file-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found out the problem. `fopen` is stupid. Using `./file.txt` or others will not work. I need to use the whole file path to do it.

```
FILE (*File) = fopen("/home/asadefa/Desktop/txt.txt", "r");
char FData[0x100];
memset(FData, '\0', 0x100);
for(z = 0; z < 0x100; ++z) {
    fgets(FData, 0x100, File);
}
fclose(File);
```

I should have noted that the full file path is used.

Comment: Why `memset`? Why a loop that will overwrite lines as soon as they are read? Why no `fclose`?

Comment: Its purpose is to make sure all the allocated memory is empty before using it.

Comment: I know it is not critical, but I do it just in case

Comment: @Asadefa Just in case what? And no, it's not really stupid; current directory notation works fine as long as it's actually correct.

Comment: You should check the return value of `fopen` and do something if it's NULL, indicating that opening the file failed (instead of getting a segfault and wondering why)

Comment: @M.M "doing something if it's NULL" Doing what?

Comment: Print an error message and exit the program would be one option

Comment: @M.M like using exit(1)

Answer (score 2):

Given the following is defined;

<s>char *TextFromFile[16];</s>

```
char TextFromFile[16]; //note "*" has been removed 
const char fileSpecToSource[] = {"some path location\\someFileName.txt"};//Windows
const char fileSpecToSource[] = {"some path location/someFileName.txt"};//Linux
```

From within a function, the statement:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(fileSpecToSource, "r");//file location is local to source directory.
```

if successful (i.e. fp != NULL), `fp` can be used as the *stream* argument in:

```
fgets(TextFromFile, 16, fp);
```

Comment: The question states the file to be read is in the same directory as the C source file. The code in this answer opens a file in the current working directory. There is no reason to expect those to be the same.

Comment: i get the error: error: initializer element is not constant
 FILE *fp = fopen(".//txt.txt", "r"); the fopen part is highlighted

Comment: @Eric - will modify my comments etc.  Thank you.

Comment: @Asadefa: That error message reveals you put the `FILE *fp = …;` statement at file scope (that is, outside of any function). Non-constant initializers are not allowed there. Put it inside a function instead.

Comment: I do that and when I try to print it, I get no warnings but I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Asadefa - Change `char *TextFromFile[16];` to `char TextFromFile[16];`

Comment: I gave it plenty of space

Comment: @Asadefa - Actually, you gave it no space.  See my edit above,     `char TextFromFile[16]; //note "*" has been removed`.  As is in the original, `fgets()` is given a pointer with no memory to write to.  Segmentation fault is usually the result, if you are lucky.

Comment: still gives me segmentation fault. Probably because it is not recognizing. How do I make a path to a file on a unix based operating system?

Comment: @Asadefa - `const char path[] = {"./file.txt"};` With the correct file name, and if the file is located in the same directory from which you are executing the executable, then this will work.

Comment: @Asadefa: Sorry, but you should stop posting follow-up questions in comments. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and comments such as “I gave it plenty of space” do not show the actual code you tried. You can post a new question with a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but do not expect to write your program by asking about every little thing.There are other resources for learning to program that are more suitable.